# How to convert string into json and change its value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a variable name state, how can i convert it into JSON object and changes its values and then convert it back to string.

**Note:** `dataField` value itself is another `JSON`, thats where i am having problem.

```
state='{"instanceId":"iaFMRu32kedGmOHC8umMQ","**dataField**":"{"id":52,"name":"CropSelection"}","validation":"incomplete","required":true,"value":"","hasValue":false,"requiresSave":true}';
```

Comment: Is `state` a string or is it an object?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it with JSON.parse()

```
var obj = JSON.parse(state);
```

then you modify what you want:

```
obj.dataField.name = "newName";
```

and finally you get your string back to the state:

```
state = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: i already tried that, it does'nt work for because there is another value in JSON format. e.g "dataField":"{"id":52,"name":"CropSelection"}".

Comment: @atul1039 See my answer. It resolves your malformed JSON

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) can be used for converting string into JSON

> var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');

[JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) can be used for converting JSON back to string

> var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build in `JSON` functions. I also fixed your JSON string. You can surrounded your `"dataField"` value with quotes which it doesn't need. It should be `{"id":52, "name":"CropSelection"}` instead of `"{"id":52, "name":"CropSelection"}"`.

```js
var state = '{"instanceId":"iaFMRu32kedGmOHC8umMQ","dataField":{"id":52, "name":"CropSelection"},"validation":"incomplete","required":true,"value":"","hasValue":false,"requiresSave":true}';

var obj = JSON.parse(state);

obj.dataField.name = 'newName';

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `JSON.parse` to convert the string to json & then update the value of dataField and again do `JSON.stringify`

Note in the string `"dataField":"{"id":52,"name":"CropSelection"}"` this is wrong, It need to be `"dataField":{"id":52,"name":"CropSelection"}`.

```js
let newDT = {
  "id": 100,
  "name": "test"
}

let state = '{"instanceId":"iaFMRu32kedGmOHC8umMQ","dataField":{"id":52,"name":"CropSelection"},"validation":"incomplete","required":true,"value":"","hasValue":false,"requiresSave":true}';

let k = JSON.parse(state);
k.dataField = newDT
console.log(JSON.stringify(k))
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer in case you posted your json incorrectly, and the value of the dataField is indeed a nested string containing json.  If so, you can parse the state, and then parse the dataField.  Change the parsed data field, then convert it back to strings incrementally.

```js
var state = '{"instanceId":"iaFMRu32kedGmOHC8umMQ","dataField":"{\\"id\\":52,\\"name\\":\\"CropSelection\\"}","validation":"incomplete","required":true,"value":"","hasValue":false,"requiresSave":true}';

var parsedState = JSON.parse(state);
console.log( parsedState );
var parsedDataField = JSON.parse( parsedState.dataField );
console.log( JSON.parse( parsedState.dataField ) );

parsedDataField.name = "New Name";
parsedState.dataField = JSON.stringify( parsedDataField );
state = JSON.stringify( parsedState );
console.log( state );
```